# initilize dictionary based on condition

Tags: c#, dictionary

I Have three lists of different classes(**MTR, AA, EIMS**). In all three classes I have common properties `prefixid` and `phasename`. Based on condition I want to group the classes by **Prefix** or **prefix and Phase** condition and create dictionaries.

I tried to implement below way but I am getting error like expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion.

How can achieve this?

```
var mtrDct = revision.IsAllowToBorrow ?
 mtrubilledTrxs.Where(x => x.AgrmntRevId == revId).GroupBy(x => x.Prefix.Id).ToDictionary(z => z.Key, z => z.ToList()) :
 mtrubilledTrxs.Where(x => x.AgrmntRevId == revId).GroupBy(x => new { x.Prefix.Id, x.Phase.ShortName }).ToDictionary(z => z.Key, z => z.ToList());

var eimsDct = revision.IsAllowToBorrow ?
 evunbilledTrxs.Where(x => x.AgrmntRevId == revId).GroupBy(x => x.Prefix.Id).ToDictionary(z => z.Key, z => z.ToList()) :
 evunbilledTrxs.Where(x => x.AgrmntRevId == revId).GroupBy(x => new { x.Prefix.Id, x.Phase }).ToDictionary(z => z.Key, z => z.ToList());

var aaDct = revision.IsAllowToBorrow ?
 aaunbilledTrxs.Where(x => x.AgrmntRevId == revId).GroupBy(x => x.Prefix.Id).ToDictionary(z => z.Key, z => z.ToList()) :
 aaunbilledTrxs.Where(x => x.AgrmntRevId == revId).GroupBy(x => new { x.Prefix.Id, x.Phase.ShortName }).ToDictionary(z => z.Key, z => z.ToList());
```

once I get these three dictionaries i need to get distinct keys from all three dictionaries.

What is the best way of doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key problem (pun intended) is that your keys are of different types.

You can solve this in 2 ways:

First way:
changing `var` to `IDictionary` (in the `System.Collections` namespace) this loses all type information about keys and values (and therefor doesn't have a problem with different key types). However, depending on what you later on do with the dictionaries this complete loss of types might not be what you're looking for:

```
IDictionary mtrDct = revision.IsAllowToBorrow ?
 mtrubilledTrxs.Where(x => x.AgrmntRevId == revId).GroupBy(x => x.Prefix.Id).ToDictionary(z => z.Key, z => z.ToList()) :
 mtrubilledTrxs.Where(x => x.AgrmntRevId == revId).GroupBy(x => new { x.Prefix.Id, x.Phase.ShortName }).ToDictionary(z => z.Key, z => z.ToList());
```

Second option:
Make the type of the keys the same, we can do this by extending the key of the first case with a dummy value:

```
var mtrDct = revision.IsAllowToBorrow ?
 mtrubilledTrxs.Where(x => x.AgrmntRevId == revId).GroupBy(x => new { x.Prefix.Id, ShortName = "" }).ToDictionary(z => z.Key, z => z.ToList()) :
 mtrubilledTrxs.Where(x => x.AgrmntRevId == revId).GroupBy(x => new { x.Prefix.Id, x.Phase.ShortName }).ToDictionary(z => z.Key, z => z.ToList());
```

This will maintains types, just keep in mind that in the first case all the `ShortName` values of the keys will be `""`.

It's hard to say for sure if this is what you need since you've not shared a lot of information about what you actually intend to do with these dictionaries.

Hope this helps and have an amazing day!

Comment: second option is better for my req knoop. after getting all distinct dict keys, i have to get records for each key frpm dict and do some calculations.

Answer (score -1):

```
var keys = (mtrDct.Keys.Union(eimsDct.Keys).Union(aaDct.Keys)).Distinct();
```

or

```
var keys =new HashSet<string>(mtrDct.Keys.Union(eimsDct.Keys).Union(aaDct.Keys));
```

if you want to materialize it and loop on it several time.

Comment: I don't think this address the core problem which is the fact that depending on the `revision.IsAllowedToBorrow` flag the keys have different types.

Comment: If you do .ToDictionary(z => z.key.ToString() ..., then the keys won't be of a different type.